# How to set IDataTypeFactory on arquillian persistence extension

Tags: java, jpa, junit, jboss-arquillian

I have hundreds of test cases, that was written with arquillian-persistence-extension. This tests are running on wildfly-managed container and they are using default H2 database, provided by wildfly. And when tests are being executed I'm getting tons of warnings like that:

```
WARN  [org.dbunit.dataset.AbstractTableMetaData] (default task-1) Potential 
problem found: 
The configured data type factory 'class
org.dbunit.dataset.datatype.DefaultDataTypeFactory' might cause problems with the
current database 'H2' (e.g. some datatypes may not be supported properly).
In rare cases you might see this message because the list of supported database
products is incomplete (list=[derby]). If so please request a java-class update
via the forums.If you are using your own IDataTypeFactory extending
DefaultDataTypeFactory,
ensure that you override getValidDbProducts() to specify the
supported database products.
```

So I have some options listed in the warning itself, but It's a bit problematic to do that, because I don't want to provide not needed DbUnit dependencies and just want to use APE on top of that.

So my question is there any easy way to define default H2 TypeFactory (that is already in wildfly) or some just disable those warning (but not affect anothers)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add following to your `arquillian.xml`:

`<extension qualifier="persistence-dbunit">
  <property name="datatypeFactory">
    org.dbunit.ext.h2.H2DataTypeFactory
  </property>
</extension>`

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to convert value [
            org.dbunit.ext.h2.H2DataTypeFactory
        ] to a class [org.dbunit.dataset.datatype.IDataTypeFactory].
 at org.jboss.arquillian.persistence.core.configuration.ConfigurationTypeConverter.convert(ConfigurationTypeConverter.java:194)
 at org.jboss.arquillian.persistence.core.configuration.ConfigurationImporter.createConfiguration(ConfigurationImporter.java:149)
 ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
            org.dbunit.ext.h2.H2DataTypeFactory

Comment: This might be classloading issue. Can you check if you don't have two different versions of dbunit on your class path?